# dvisvgm invoked multiply for saved boxes with 4ht

Tags: make4ht, dvisvgm

With the following MWE, I observe `dvisvgm` is called twice instead of once:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{pgfornament}
\tikzset{
  myfroufrou/.pic={
    \node {\pgfornament[height=1cm]{79}};
  }
}
\usepackage{storebox}
\newstorebox{\froufroubox}

\title{Some Book}
\subtitle{A novel}
\author{Some Author}

\begin{document}
\storebox{\froufroubox}{%
  { \tikz \pic{myfroufrou}; }
}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\blindtext{}

\usestorebox{\froufroubox}
\blindtext{}
\usestorebox{\froufroubox}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `pdflatex` seems to create the TikZ picture only once, storing it in the `storebox` as expected, and using it multiple times. I can confirm this e.g. by adding a `\special{dvisgm:raw something}` to the `tikzpicture` and counting the number of warnings.

However, compiling this with `make4ht` via:

```
make4ht --utf8 book.tex "svg"
```

shows `dvisvgm` is called twice, and both invocations seem to write the very same `<jobname>0x.svg` file. In my final document, I want to use a `froufrou`-like separator multiple times, so saving some compute time would be advantageous.
Using a `savebox` instead of a `storebox` does not change the observed behaviour.

Is there a way to reduce the number of `dvisvgm` invocations to the amount of unique pictures (in this case, one)?

Comment: `storebox` does not support `dvisvgm`, but defaults to `\savebox`. You may try pkg `xsavebox` instead: `\xsbox{froufroubox}{...}` and `\xusebox{froufroubox}` or just `\thefroufroubox` for insertion. No previous box allocation required.

Comment: `xsavebox` is working really well for me, many thanks, @AlexG ! I was not aware of it before. This brillantly solves both the `dvisvgm` and `pdflatex` use cases I have (in combination with the answer below).

Comment: I must correct my statement — it seems that using `xsavebox` works perfectly well with `pdflatex`, and with `dvisvgm` also only a single SVG is created, but after `htlatex` things go wrong and the box is rendered wheteit is defined only (and not upon use).

Comment: Oh, I haven't actually tested with htlatex, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dvisvgm_hashes` make4ht extension. It speeds up the SVG compilation because it converts multiple pages in parallel. It also doesn't compile images that didn't change from the last compilation.

Use this command:

```
make4ht -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, @michal.h21 ! Especially in combination with `xsavebox` as @AlexG pointed out in a comment above, this works extremely well. I somehow did not realize the nice functionality `dvisvgm_hashes` provides in the documentation before, but now that I read it again, it's clearly the way to go and a huge time-saver :-).

Comment: I have to correct myself: `xsavebox` does not work as expected (see my comment above). Using `storebox` or `savebox` as in the example, and `html5+dvisvgm_hashes` works fine, however, I still get two SVG files, which are basically the same. Diffing them, I see there is 0.1% of difference in the `viewBox`, `height` and all coordinates. So it seems the very same TikZ picture is regarded as different. 
This means while `dvisvgm_hashes` will run faster, the resulting HTML will include two different SVGs (or many more copies), resulting in much larger web content. 
Is there a way around that?

Comment: The multiple-slightly-differently-sized-SVGs-issue I described seems limited to TeXlive 2021. With TeXlive 2022, only a single `svg` is generated, i.e. it works as expected. 
Thanks! :-)